# Get transactionId from Steam on DLC Purchase

Tags: steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

i'm trying to implement some custom handling on SteamDLC payment. When client is loading this client send to our server information about which DLC is bought and which is not.

But for accounting purposes i need pair this DLC payment with reports. From client i have information only about steamId and appId (which is DLC id).

Is here any process how can i retrieve information about transaction on specific DLC?

I checked documentation but i don't find anything related to this problem.

Thanks